# Boost Asio not properly reading

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, asio

In my code I have both a client and server socket set up to simulate interaction between the two using asio. Unfortunately, something is failing in my read() and I'm not entirely sure what I'm not passing in properly and why. When I run it, it'll wait indefinitely. Might it be something I'm missing?

```
boost::asio::io_service ioservice;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioservice);
tcp::socket client(ioservice);
tcp::socket server(ioservice);

boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 2222);

acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
acceptor.bind(endpoint);
acceptor.listen();
acceptor.async_accept(server, &acc_handle);

client.async_connect(endpoint, &conn_handle);

ioservice.run();

boost::asio::write(client, boost::asio::buffer("test"));

boost::asio::streambuf bfr;
boost::asio::read(client, bfr);
```

EDIT: Added handlers, they just log information so I'm omitting their definition.

Comment: this isn't real code. async_connect etc require handlers.

Comment: You're writing to the client socket, but not reading from the server socket (which is where you're intending 'test' to emerge from). No where have you written anything to the server socket, so there is nothing to read from the client socket.

Comment: @bazza that's how network services usually work though, the other party is usually not the same program.

Comment: @bazza The problem if I try to read from the server socket is that I'll get a "Bad File Descriptor" error, which lead me to believe I couldn't use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the real flow of code, then nothing after `ioservice.run();` gets executed until you stop it at which point no `ioservice` operations get executed either. The code needs to reside in those async handlers.

It's hard to get a hang on what is going on since you've not included the handlers' definitions but I will try to make a projection:

The `acc_handle` should contain a `server.async_receive(read_buffer, [](const boost::system::error_code&, size_t){...});`.

The `conn_handle`, should contain a `client.async_send(write_buffer, endpoint, [](const boost::system::error_code&, size_t){...});` at which point you should be able to see the server's receive handler firing.

All that being said, I strongly recommend you going through the relevant examples at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html as they are clearly and cleanly written.